# Javascript json data post to MVC returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, post, null

I am working in an MVC .Net web app. I am trying to post data back to the controller. Here is the Javascript/Angularjs I am using.

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Save',
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.data[0]),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
```

when I look at this in fiddler I see the following (Shortened for brevity)

```
        {"BL_BASIC_DDL":"","BL_BASIC_TB":"Foo Bar","BL_BASIC_NB":""}
```

but when I try to get this in my C# I either get a null object or a dictionary which contains the controller and action names that where called and nothing else. Here is a list of action signatures that I have tried that have failed. The data I am returning is highly dynamic and will be parsed through so a static typed object is not what I am shooting for.

```
        public JsonResult Save(string values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save(List<Tuple<string, string>> values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save(Dictionary<string, string> values);
        // values != null
        // values.Count == 2
        // values["controller"] = "Coverages"
        // values["action"] = "Save"
        public JsonResult Save(object values);
        // values != null
        // values is unknown type, no data appears accessible
        public JsonResult Save(dynamic values);
        // values != null
        // values is unknown type, no data appears accessible
        public JsonResult Save(FormCollection values);
        // values != not null
        // values.Count == 0
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]string values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]List<Tuple<string, string>> values);
        // values == null
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]Dictionary<string, string> values);
        // values != null
        // values.Count == 2
        // values["controller"] = "Coverages"
        // values["action"] = "Save"
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]object values);
        // values != null
        // values is unknown type, no data appears accessible
        public JsonResult Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody]dynamic values);
        // values != null
        // values is unknown type, no data appears accessible
        public JsonResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(DictionaryModelBinder))] Dictionary<string, string> values); // example I found online but still did not work
        // values != null
        // values.Count == 2
        // values["controller"] = "Coverages"
        // values["action"] = "Save"
```

I tried t see if I could find the raw data in the request object but I failed to do this as well. The ModelBinder binder example I found while trying to find a solution to this problem. Unfortunately all it found was the controller and action names.

Would anyone have any recommendations for me on what might be going wrong or how I can get my data?

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the response from the server, on the front-end?

Comment: Right now the Save method doesn't return anything as I have not gotten that far yet.

If you are talking about any possible exceptions none are thrown.

If you are talking about what the value is of the "values" parameter it varies. I will edit my question to illustrate.